# Program repeating itself issue

Tags: c, char, newline, scanf, format-specifiers

I'm trying to create a program that is asking the user to choose what stage he would like to play in and then the program asks him if he would like to play again or no and for some reason the if the user enters 'y'- the program repeat it self but without running the function "stages".

```
int main()
{
    while (again == 'y')
    {

        getStage(); 
    }

    if (again == 'n')
    {
        printf("BYE BYE!");
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}

/*
    Function "getStage"-
        - gets a choice from the user about the stage he wants to play on
          and checks if the choice is proper.
        - Transfers the program to the "randCode" function to make secret code.
        - Transfers the program to the "stages" function
*/

void getStage()
{

    choice= 0;

    do
    {
        printf("What stage would you like to choose? Choose Wisely: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        fflush(stdin);
        system("COLOR 07");
    } while(choice < 1 || choice > 4);

    randCode();

    stages(choice);

    printf("Whould you like to play again? (y / n): ");
    scanf("%c", &again);

}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior.

Comment: This is `fflush(stdin);` undefined behavior and just add a scpace before `%c` in the format specifier.

Comment: You should add return 0 at the end of main and main itself should be declared as int main (void)

Comment: I believe `again` is a global variable. Also try printing "*In stages*" at the very beginning of `stages` function.

Answer (score 4):

In your `getStage()` function code, you need to change

```
 scanf("%c", &again);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &again);
      ^^  // note the space here
```

to *skip* the newline character present in input buffer.

To elaborate, when you enter an input and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, it stores the input followed by the newline character caused by  <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

In the next iteration, that `newline` present in the input buffer servs as the input to the next `%c` format specifier which makes the `scanf()` to *skip* a step.

That said,

1. `fflush(stdin)` is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Get rid of it.
2. `int main()` should be `int main(void)` at least to conform to the standard.

Comment: But without the fflush(stdin) the loop is just infinite

Comment: @Nathan1982 and why's that?

Comment: I don't know but without it it just prints "What stage would you like to choose? Choose Wisely:" without stopping.

Comment: @Nathan1982 and that's precisely why you should be checking the return value of `scanf()`

Comment: Ok, i removed the fflush(stdin) and added a space before the %c and it still doesn't work. My original code is longer then this but its over 300 hundred lines, Can i paste it?